# JQuery Validate appears to conflict with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a form which uses Bootstrap and JQuery. I am trying to validate the form using JQuery validate, but whenever I try to add the validate_min.js script, it stops the rest of my form working. I've cut the form down to this example.

I have a text field, with some preset values in a drop-down menu. Without the validation, I can select a preset value, and it is inserted into the text field. This stops working if the jquery.validate_min.js line is uncommented. (If I do uncomment the line, the form validates correctly, so that part of it is working.)

The html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/forms.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"</script>-->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/form-test2.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Test Form Layout</h1>
</div>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="#" id="validate_test">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="preset_box">Preset test</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="preset_box" name="preset_box">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
                  data-toggle="dropdown">Presets <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
            <li><a href="#" id="pre_1">Preset 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="pre_2">Preset 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="pre_3">Preset 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div> <!-- input-group-btn -->
      </div> <!-- input-group -->
    </div>   <!-- col-sm-3 -->
  </div> <!-- form-group -->


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>

<!--
<script>
  $("#dustdistform").validate({
//    ignore: ".novalidate",
    rules: {
    }
  });
</script>
-->
</body>
</html>
```

form-test2.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#pre_1").click(function() {
        $("#preset_box").val("10");
    });

    $("#pre_2").click(function() {
        $("#preset_box").val("20");
    });

    $("#pre_3").click(function() {
        $("#preset_box").val("30");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are trying to validate a form then it can be done easily like this.
 put your form and input name and then check if its empty.

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably what I'll resort to if nobody can solve my question, but the real form is quite long, and I want to perform quite a range of validation on it. JQuery validation works really nicely for what I'm trying to do, except it breaks my form!